# Laravel 4 call mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, laravel, laravel-4

im trying to migrate from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4

In Laravel 3 I used to call procedure like this and everything worked fine.

```
public function get_gen_dist($skip = 0, $take = 0) {
    $countries = Country::skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        DB::query('CALL dist_proc(' . $country->id . ');');
    }
}
```

In Laravel 4 I changed "DB::query" to "DB::raw", no errors, and procedure is not called (at least procedure not executed), 
var_dump'ed result with "DB::raw" looks

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression)[269]
protected 'value' => string 'CALL dist_proc(107)' (length=19)
```

Also tried:

```
...    
foreach ($countries as $country) {
      $country_id = $country->id;
      $db = DB::connection()->getPdo();
      $stmt = $db->prepare("CALL dist_proc(?);");
      $stmt->bindValue(1, $country_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->execute();
}
```

but on second loop call I get

```
ErrorException
Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 5. Packet size=10
```

tried to "$stmt->closeCursor();" after "$stmt->execute();", but now success.

Without loop or if loop runs only once, procedure executes successully.

How to call procedure in loop?

Thank you

Comment: random question. How do you manage store procedures in Laravel? do you create a migration script for it?  And when do you use stored proc? does that mean you don't use Eloquent anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it this way:

```
public function get_gen_dist($skip = 0, $take = 0) {
    $countries = Country::skip($skip)->take($take)->get();
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        DB::statement(DB::raw('CALL dist_proc(' . $country->id . ');'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error "Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 5. Packet size=10" as with using PDO. And error is pointed to "...vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php -> return $statement->fetchAll($me->getFetchMode());"

Comment: This is not a Laravel problem, might be a MySQL one. There are some people talking about it here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68359. Looks like you have to fetch your records or write your stored procedure differently.

Comment: Did you find solution to the problem? If yes, please share it. This accepted answer still throwing the same error.